# Meteor API integration with close.io

Tags: javascript, curl, meteor, request

I'm trying to figure out how Meteor can work with close.io.
[Documentation](http://developer.close.io/)

For example, we have a curl command to retrieve a single Lead from close.io

```
curl -XGET "https://app.close.io/api/v1/lead/{id}/" -u yourapikey:
```

API key is used. Meteor has methods

```
HTTP.get(url, [options], [asyncCallback])
```

So we can use this url here like

```
HTTP.get("https://app.close.io/api/v1/lead/{id}/")
```

but how can we apply the API key here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found an npm package 
[Close IO](https://www.npmjs.com/package/close.io)
It helps to intergrate Close IO with your application